# Add latest Microsoft Edge (Win10) browser to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-edgedriver

Tried by adding the below code.

```
"capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
            "platform": "WIN10",
            "maxInstances": 1
        },
]
```

and passed it to command line

```
start java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="../../Resources/Drivers/msedgedriver.exe" -jar "%SELSERV%" -role node -nodeConfig ..\ConfigFiles\NodeConfig.json
```

[I am getting the microsoft edge legacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbUlZ.png)

I need the latest microsoft edge (Based on chromium) in selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Edge browser being chromium based, try using the below node configurations:

```
"capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "Chrome",
            "platform": "WIN10",
            "maxInstances": 1
        },
]
```

And then execute the below command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="../../Resources/Drivers/msedgedriver.exe" -jar "%SELSERV%" -role node -nodeConfig ..\ConfigFiles\NodeConfig.json
```

Notice the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property being set to msedgedriver.exe file.

Comment: Tried as per the above code. I didn't get any images (Browsers) in grid console.